# Should I use StatefulWidget or a Cubit for this case?

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have to build a single page that consists of let's say a switch and a button. The user can continue to the next screen only if he has turned on the switch, then the user can press the button and go to the next screen. This is a quite simple case and I was wondering if using a Cubit here is an overkill or should I use StatefulWidget here?

- Why is better to use here a Cubit?
- Why is better to use here a StatefulWidget?
- Should I, in general, use StatefulWidget for simple cases like the above one?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Answer (score 2):

For a simple case like this, using a `StatefulWidget` would be sufficient. Using a `Cubit` might be overkill and can add unnecessary complexity to your code.

However, using a `Cubit` in simple cases can promote the ***separation of concerns***, make your code more ***testable*** and ***maintainable***, and make it easier to ***add new features*** later on.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to manage simple, well contained state (e.g. a bool in your case) in `State` rather than trying to reach for something more complicated like a Change/StateNotifier, Riverpod,  BLoC, etc. If your states starts to span across multiple layers or screens, it *might* be time to start reaching for something a little more sophisticated. That could be one of the previously mentioned approaches or simply just parameters and callbacks.